# Refactoring a loop?

Tags: php, algorithm, refactoring, large-data

I want to loop more than 200,000 user datasets to filter 30,000 products，how can i optimize this nested big loop to get best performance?

```
  //settings , 5 max per user, can up to 200,000
   $settings = array(...);

   //all prods, up to 30,000
   $prods = array(...);

   //all prods category relation map, up to 2 * 30,000
   $prods_cate_ref_all = array(...);

   //msgs filtered by settings saved yesterday , more then 100 * 200,000
   $msg_all = array(...);

   //filter counter
   $j = 0;

   //filter result
   $res = array();

   foreach($settings as $set){

       foreach($prods as $k=>$p){

           //filter prods by site_id 
           if ($set['site_id'] != $p['site_id']) continue;

               //filter prods by city_id , city_id == 0 is all over the country
           if ($set['city_id'] != $p['city_id'] && $p['city_id'] > 0) continue;

           //muti settings of a user may get same prods
               if (prod_in($p['id'], $set['uuid'], $res)) continue;

            //prods filtered by settings saved  to msg table yesterday
           if (msg_in($p['id'], $set['uuid'], $msg_all)) continue;

               //filter prods by category id 
           if (!prod_cate_in($p['id'], $set['cate_id'], $prods_cate_ref_all)) continue;

            //filter prods by tags of set not in prod title, website ...
                $arr = array($p['title'], $p['website'], $p['detail'], $p['shop'], $p['tags']);
           if (!tags_in($set['tags'], $arr)) continue; 

               $res[$j]['name'] = $v['name'];
           $res[$j]['prod_id'] = $p['id'];
               $res[$j]['uuid'] = $v['uuid'];
               $res[$j]['msg'] = '...';
               $j++;
       }

   }

   save_to_msg($res);

function prod_in($prod_id, $uuid, $prod_all){
    foreach($prod_all as $v){
    if ($v['prod_id'] == $prod_id && $v['uuid'] == $uuid)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function prod_cate_in($prod_id, $cate_id, $prod_cate_all){
    foreach($prod_cate_all as $v){
    if ($v['prod_id'] == $prod_id && $v['cate_id'] == $cate_id)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function tags_in($tags, $arr){
    $tag_arr = explode(',', str_replace('，', ',', $tags));
    foreach($tag_arr as $v){
    foreach($arr as $a){
        if(strpos($a, strtolower($v)) !== false){
        return true;
        }
    }
    }
    return false;
}

function msg_in($prod_id, $uuid, $msg_all){
    foreach($msg_all as $v){
    if ($v['prod_id'] == $prod_id && $v['uuid'] == $uuid)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

UPDATE:
Thanks a lot.
Yes, data is in mysql, Below is the main struct:

```
-- user settings to filter prods, 5 max per user
CREATE TABLE setting(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   uuid VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   tags VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   site_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   city_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   cate_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   addtime INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
   KEY `idx_setting_uuid` (`uuid`),
   KEY `idx_setting_tags` (`tags`),
   KEY `idx_setting_city_id` (`city_id`),
   KEY `idx_setting_cate_id` (`cate_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE users(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   uuid VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),   
   UNIQUE KEY `idx_unique_uuid` (`uuid`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


-- filtered prods
CREATE TABLE msg_list(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   uuid VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   prod_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   msg TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `idx_ml_uuid` (`uuid`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



-- prods and prod_cate_ref table in another database, so can not join it


CREATE TABLE prod(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   website VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT ' site name ',
   site_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   city_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   tags VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   detail VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   shop VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `idx_prod_tags` (`tags`),
   KEY `idx_prod_site_id` (`site_id`),
   KEY `idx_prod_city_id` (`city_id`),
   KEY `idx_prod_mix` (`site_id`,`city_id`,`tags`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE prod_cate_ref(
   id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
   prod_id INT NOT NULL NULL DEFAULT 0,
   cate_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL NULL DEFAULT 0,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `idx_pcr_mix` (`prod_id`,`cate_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


-- ENGINE all is myisam
```

I don't know how to use just one sql to fetch all.

Comment: I assume you are fetching this from a database. I also assume you are using a SQL database. Then why not make use of `JOINs` and `WHERE` clauses?

Comment: Where do you get the settings from? A database?

Comment: That's one helluva lot of data to be storing in PHP arrays. Is this coming out of a database or something?

Comment: I agree with NullUserEsception, you should be doing this in MySQL if possible.

Comment: Can you not use a lookup table? Just iterate through one of the sets, looking up the other set of data... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for inspiring me, I finally got it, it's a so simple method indeed, but a huge step!

i regroup the data in $prods_cate_ref_all and $msg_all (use the two function at the end), 
also the result array $res, 
then use strpos and in_array instead of three iterate function (prod_in msg_in prod_cate_in) ,

i got an amazing 50x speed up!!! 
As the data goes larger, the effect becomes more effective.

```
  //settings , 5 max per user, can up to 200,000
   $settings = array(...);

   //all prods, up to 30,000
   $prods = array(...);

   //all prods category relation map, up to 2 * 30,000
   $prods_cate_ref_all = get_cate_ref_all();

   //msgs filtered by settings saved yesterday , more then 100 * 200,000
   $msg_all = get_msg_all();

   //filter counter
   $j = 0;

   //filter result
   $res = array();


  foreach($settings as $set){

       foreach($prods as $p){

       $res_uuid_setted = false;

       $uuid = $set['uuid'];

       if (isset($res[$uuid])){
           $res_uuid_setted = true;
       }

       //filter prods by site_id 
       if ($set['site_id'] != $p['site_id']) 
               continue;

       //filter prods by city_id , city_id == 0 is all over the country
       if ($set['city_id'] != $p['city_id'] && $p['city_id'] > 0) 
               continue;


       //muti settings of a user may get same prods
       if ($res_uuid_setted)
           //in_array faster than strpos if item < 1000
           if (in_array($p['id'], $res[$uuid]['prod_ids']))
           continue;

       //prods filtered by settings saved  to msg table yesterday
       if (isset($msg_all[$uuid]))
           //strpos faster than in_array in large data
           if (false !== strpos($msg_all[$uuid], ' ' . $p['id'] . ' '))
           continue;

       //filter prods by category id 
       if (false === strpos($prods_cate_ref_all[$p['id']], ' ' . $set['cate_id'] . ' '))
           continue;

       $arr = array($p['title'], $p['website'], $p['detail'], $p['shop'], $p['tags']);
       if (!tags_in($set['tags'], $arr))
           continue;


       $res[$uuid]['prod_ids'][] = $p['id'];

       $res[$uuid][] = array(
        'name' => $set['name'],
        'prod_id' => $p['id'],
        'msg' => '',
       );

       }

   }


function get_msg_all(){

    $temp = array();
    $msg_all = array(
        array('uuid' => 312, 'prod_id' => 211),
        array('uuid' => 1227, 'prod_id' => 31),
        array('uuid' => 1, 'prod_id' => 72),
        array('uuid' => 993, 'prod_id' => 332),
        ...
    );

    foreach($msg_all as $k=>$v){
    if (!isset($temp[$v['uuid']])) 
        $temp[$v['uuid']] = ' ';

    $temp[$v['uuid']] .= $v['prod_id'] . ' ';
    }

    $msg_all = $temp;
    unset($temp);

    return $msg_all;
}


function get_cate_ref_all(){

    $temp = array();
    $cate_ref = array(
        array('prod_id' => 3, 'cate_id' => 21),
        array('prod_id' => 27, 'cate_id' => 1),
        array('prod_id' => 1, 'cate_id' => 232),
        array('prod_id' => 3, 'cate_id' => 232),
        ...
    );

    foreach($cate_ref as $k=>$v){
    if (!isset($temp[$v['prod_id']]))
        $temp[$v['prod_id']] = ' ';

    $temp[$v['prod_id']] .= $v['cate_id'] . ' ';
    }
    $cate_ref = $temp;
    unset($temp);

    return $cate_ref;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're already have the larger set in the outer loop it's hard to tell where you can optimize this. You could inline the functions code to spare the function calls or partly unroll from your many foreach's.

For example, inside this function

```
function tags_in($tags, $arr){
    $tag_arr = explode(',', str_replace('，', ',', $tags));
    foreach($tag_arr as $v){
    foreach($arr as $a){
        if(strpos($a, strtolower($v)) !== false){
        return true;
        }
    }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You're basically using the arrays for string access. Do strings more direct (Note: full tag matching, yours did partial matches):

```
function tags_in($tags, $arr)
{
    $tags = ', '.strtolower($tags).', ';

    foreach($arr as $tag)
    {
        if (false !== strpos($tags, ', '.$tag.', ')
          return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But as you've got a large amount of data, things will just take long.

- Only optimize your release build.
- Do only small, decent changes.
- Run your tests after each change.
- Profile each change against *representative Real World* test data.

So next to smaller code movements and changes you're probably looking for scale. If you can solve problems partly before, you could do a map and reduce strategy. Maybe you're already using a document based database that offers an interface for that.